# Any material on complexification?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

These days, I met a problem on linear algebra:

> Suppose $A,B$ are real matrices. If there's a complex unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^*AU=B$, where $U^*=\overline U^\top$, namely, the conjugate transpose of $U$, then there's a real orthogonal matrix $O$ such that $O^\top AO=B$.

I tried but failed. It seems that I lack some advanced tools. By some search work, I've found [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/140890). **However, I want to determine whether my preceding thoughts would work, so I post a question here to look for some requests.**

Note that if $P$ is unitary, then $P^{-1}=P^*$ and if $P$ is orthogonal, then $P^{-1}=P^\top$, therefore either conditions is equivalent to $AP=PB$, where $P=U$ or $O$. Consider the matrix space $M_n(\mathbb R)$ and its complexification $M_n(\mathbb C)$. The matrices $P$ such that $AP=PB$ form a subspace of $M_n$. Denote $O_n\subseteq M_n(\mathbb R)$ the group of orthogonal matrices, and $U_n\subseteq M_n(\mathbb C)$ the group of unitary matrices. We consider $U_n$ the complexification of $O_n$. The original problem (somewhat generalized) could be described as follows:

> Suppose $V\subseteq M_n(\mathbb R)$ is a subspace, and $^\mathbb CV$ is its complexication in $M_n(\mathbb C)$. If the complexification of $V\cap O_n$, i.e. $^\mathbb CV\cap U_n$ is non-empty, then $V\cap O_n\neq\emptyset$ per se.

I have tried some further generalizations, but eventually I found it's wrong. In order to explicate my idea clearly, I write it here:

> If the intersection of complexification of quadratic hypersurfaces is non-empty, then the intersection of themselves is non-empty too, where quadratic hypersurface is the zero set of a quadratic form $r(x)=\langle x,x\rangle$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a bilinear form (not necessarily symmetric), and the complexification of such a hypersurface is the zero set of $^\mathbb Cr(x+iy)=\langle x,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle+i\langle x,y\rangle-i\langle y,x\rangle\triangleq{}^\mathbb C\langle x+iy,x+iy\rangle$

**Note that the constraints of $O_n$ and $U_n$ are just of this kind.**

It's wrong, since $x^2=1,y^2=1,xy+yx=0$ has no solution, but $\bar xx=1,\bar yy=1, \bar xy+\bar yx=0$ has solution $(x,y)=(1,i)$.

Intuitively, the failure comes from $\bar xy+\bar yx=0$, whose zero set is somewhat *singular*. By contrast, at least, $SO_n$ and $SU_n$ are well-known analytic manifolds.

I want to learn more on the topic of the following schema:

> Suppose there's a complexification functor betwen $\mathbb R^N$ and $\mathbb C^N$. Some structured $W$ is non-empty iff its complexification $^\mathbb CW$ is non-empty.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: 6 years later you answer [my question on complexification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518259/nonstandard-definitions-of-complexifications). Do you have any answers for your question now?