# Nonstandard definitions of complexifications

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here are some:

---

I notice that the standard definitions of complexification of an $\mathbb R-$ vector space are as follows:

1. In terms of direct sums, $V^{\mathbb C, sum} := (V^2,J)$ where $J$ is the almost complex structure $J: V^2 \to V^2, J(v,w):=(-w,v)$ which corresponds to the complex structure $s_{(J,V^2)}: \mathbb C \times V^2 \to V^2,$$ s_{(J,V^2)}(a+bi,(v,w))$$:=s_{V^2}(a,(v,w))+s_{V^2}(b,J(v,w))$$=a(v,w)+bJ(v,w)$ where $s_{V^2}$ is the real scalar multiplication on $V^2$ extended to $s_{(J,V^2)}$. In particular, $i(v,w)=(-w,v)$
2. In terms of tensor products $V^{\mathbb C, tensor} := V \bigotimes \mathbb C$. Here, $\mathbb C$ scalar multiplication is as follows on elementary tensors $z(v \otimes \alpha) := v \otimes (z\alpha)$, for $v \in V$ and $z, \alpha \in \mathbb C$.

I notice we can have a different definition for sum $V^{\mathbb C, sum, -J} := (V^2,-J)$, where $\mathbb C$ scalar multiplication is now $i(v,w)=(-J)(v,w) := -J(v,w) := (w,-v)$.

- Note: In this notation, $V^{\mathbb C, sum, J} = V^{\mathbb C, sum}$.

---

Question 1: Does $V^{\mathbb C, sum, -J}$ somehow correspond to $V^{\mathbb C, tensor, f(z)=\overline z} := (V \bigotimes \mathbb C, f(z)=\overline z)$, where $\mathbb C$ scalar multiplication is as follows on elementary tensors $z(v \otimes \alpha) := v \otimes (f(z)\alpha)$ $ = v \otimes (\overline z \alpha)$, for $v \in V$ and $z, \alpha \in \mathbb C$?

- Note: In this notation, $V^{\mathbb C, tensor, f(z)=id_{\mathbb C}(z)} = (V \bigotimes \mathbb C)$

  - Note: Any general correspondence between almost complex structures $K$ on $V^2$ and the $f$'s on $V \bigotimes \mathbb C$ may be reserved for Question 2. For Question 1, I'm interested to see if $V^{\mathbb C, sum, -J}$ and $V^{\mathbb C, tensor, f(z)=\overline z}$ are 'more isomorphic' than $V^{\mathbb C, sum, -J}$ and $V^{\mathbb C, sum, J}$ (I think [Gauthier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611884/significance-of-unique-isomorphism) would say they are not $\mathbb C$-isomorphic by the identity map or something) in the sense that  $V^{\mathbb C, sum, -J}$ and $V^{\mathbb C, tensor, f(z)=\overline z}$ are not just $\mathbb C$-isomorphic, but $\mathbb C$-isomorphic is some unique way, I guess, like Theorem 3.1 of [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611884/significance-of-unique-isomorphism).

Question 2: What are these mysterious $f$'s on $V \bigotimes \mathbb C$, and what is the (or 'a' instead of 'the') correspondence, if any, with the almost complex structures $K$ on $V^2 = (V^{\mathbb C, sum})_{\mathbb R}$ (for tensor product, I think $V \bigotimes \mathbb R^2 = (V^{\mathbb C, tensor})_{\mathbb R}$) ?

- Update based on Yai0Phah's answer: It looks like these mysterious $f$'s are '$\mathbb R$-algebra endormophisms' of $\mathbb C$. Then each '$\mathbb R$-algebra endormophism' $f$ gives almost complex structure $J_f(v) := f(i)v$ on $V^2$. However, it might be the case that not every almost complex structure $K$ on $V^2$ comes from some '$\mathbb R$-algebra endormophisms' $f$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then first one should be correct (note that $\mathbb C\cong\mathbb R\oplus i\mathbb R$ as real vector spaces). The second one might not be as easy as you thought. The problem is that, $V\oplus V$ is no more special than any real vector spaces of even dimension, and there are pretty many almost complex structure on that. For example, let $E$ be a real vector space of even dimension, and $u,v\in E$ two linearly independent vectors, then there exists an almost complex structure $K\colon E\to E$ such that $K(u)=v$ (and consequently $K(v)=-u$).

Comment: @Yai0Phah Thanks. 1. For the first question, what then is the relationship between $f(z) = \overline z$ and $-J$? 2. What exactly is the relevance of $\mathbb C_{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R + 0i \bigoplus 0+\mathbb Ri$ here? 3. For the second question, do you mean that it might be hard to find $f$ since there are a lot of $K$'s in the sense that any 2 linearly independent vectors give rise to some (probably non-unique) $K$? 4. In your opinion, do you think this [could/should be on-topic on overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350788/nonstandard-definitions-of-complexifications)?

Comment: By the way, it is clearly improper for MO.

Comment: Ignore my comment about $\mathbb C\cong\mathbb R\oplus i\mathbb R$. This was devoted to the "universal" case of $\mathbb C$, but seemingly more difficult to explain.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Ok, thanks. I guess we'll refer to your answer now.

Comment: @Yai0Phah About MO, How is [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351807/is-the-complement-of-a-zero-dimensional-subset-of-the-plane-path-connected) not more elementary than [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350788/nonstandard-definitions-of-complexifications) ?

Comment: I don't think that it benefits you a lot to monitor the "quality" of questions on MO. If I understand correctly, MO is a place to discuss research level problems. Research level doesn't mean that it is more difficult than classical ones (and IMHO, classical ones are sometimes much more nontrivial than those appear in research). And there are well-known mathematicians answering questions here, especially those engaged in teaching. It seems more beneficial to ask questions about classical objects here.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to clarify your questions: in fact, essentially your questions have nothing to do with complexifications. The first thing is that: all complex vectors spaces $E$ are real vector spaces (called the underlying real vector space) with an almost complex structure $J\colon E\to E$ being a map of real vector spaces given by multiplication by $i$, that is, $v\mapsto iv$. On the other hand, given a real vector space $E$, almost complex structures $J\colon E\to E$ give rise to complex vector spaces $E_J$ given by $(a+bi)v=av+bJ(v)$. The data of whether the complex vector space $E$ comes from complexification or "how" it comes from is irrelevant.

Second, given a $\mathbb C$-vector space $E$ and an $\mathbb R$-algebra morphism $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, we have a $\mathbb C$-vector space, denoted by $f_*E$, of which the underlying real vector space is the real vector space $E$ with the multiplication $\mathbb C\times f_*E\to f_*E$ given by $(c,v)\mapsto f(c)v$ where the multiplication $f(c)v$ is taken in the complex vector space $E$.

Given these, I would like to rephrase your two questions as follows:

1. Let $E$ be a complex vector space which corresponds to an almost complex structure $J\colon E\to E$, and let $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be the complex conjugate (which is, of course, an $\mathbb R$-algebra endomorphism). Then the almost complex structure corresponds to the complex vector space $f_*E$ is given by $-J\colon E\to E$.
2. Let $E$ be a complex vector space. Does all almost complex structures come from those correspond to complex vector spaces $f_*E$ where $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ runs through all $\mathbb R$-algebra endomorphisms (Exercise: there are only two $\mathbb R$-algebra endomorphisms on $\mathbb C$)?

Then the first statement is clearly true and the second is false if $E\neq0$. As explained in the comment, it could be seen from the following proposition:

Let $E$ be a real vector space of even dimension and let $u,v\in E$ be two $\mathbb R$-linearly independent vectors, then there exists an almost complex structure $J\colon E\to E$ such that $J(u)=v$ and $J(v)=-u$.

Comment: Thanks Yai0Phah. 1. The $f$'s in question have to be $\mathbb R$-algebra endomorphisms? 2. Do the $f$'s at least embed in the space of almost complex structures? It looks like for every $f$, we can have some corresponding almost complex structure. For example, on $E=(E_{\mathbb R}, J)$, the identity on $\mathbb C$ corresponds to $J$ on $E_{\mathbb R}$ and conjugation on $\mathbb C$ corresponds to $-J$ on $E_{\mathbb R}$

Comment: Maybe we cannot find an $f$ for every $J$, but I think we can find a $J$ for every $f$: It appears that the complex structure $\mu_f: \mathbb C \times E_{\mathbb R} \to E_{\mathbb R},$ $\mu_f(z,v) := f(z)v$ uniquely corresponds (based on correspondence in Huybrechts) to the almost complex structure $J_f(v) := (\mu_f)_i(v) := \mu_f(i,v)$ such that $(a+ib) \cdot v := av + bJ_f(v) := av + b\mu_f(i,v) := av + bf(i)v$.

Comment: Note: I slightly edited post.

Comment: Wait, about my follow-up question 1 about the $\mathbb R$-algebra, I think this should have two parts instead: 1a. Does every $\mathbb R$-algebra endomorphism give a different definition of complexification $\mathbb C$-isomorphic to the one with $f(z)=id_{\mathbb C}(z)=z$? 1b. For every definition of complexification as $z(v \otimes \alpha) := v \otimes (f(z)\alpha)$, is $f$ necessarily an $\mathbb R$-algebra endomorphism?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon It is not clear in the question what $f$ is supposed to be and I guess from the context that $f$ is an $\mathbb R$-algebra endomorphism. You need to clarify the notations and the definitions in the question. The clearer the question is, the more people can understand and help.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon By the way, it seems to me that you are not fully prepared for the prerequisites of Huybrechts' book. In particular, it seems that you are not acquainted with rings (especially, commutative ones) and modules, which will be used in Huybrechts' book. The classical textbook is Atiyah-Macdonald's *Commutative Algebra*, and it might be helpful to read Reid's *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra* (with more illustrations about geometric intuitions) and look occasionally at Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra* (voluminous, but more intuitive than A-M).

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon If you don't know the classification of finitely generated modules over a PID, you also need to learn this topic from, say, Artin's *Algebra*, or Jacobson's *Basic Algebra* (just go to the related chapter directly). Sorry, I don't have much time to address all questions.

Comment: Yai0Phah, thanks. About the last two comments, again, [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme)

Answer (score 1):

Complexification is a *functor* from the category of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces to the category of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. To specify a functor we need to specify:

1. For each $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$, a way to produce a complex vector space $V^\mathbb{C}$.
2. For each $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $g: V \to W$, a way to produce a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $g^\mathbb{C}: V^\mathbb{C} \to W^\mathbb{C}$.

To be truly functorial, the identity map on $V$ needs to complexify to the identity map on $V^\mathbb{C}$, and composition of maps must complexify nicely: $(g \circ f)^\mathbb{C} = g^\mathbb{C} \circ f^\mathbb{C}$.

Don't forget to define how to complexify a *linear map*, not just the vector space.

---

Here are four different ways to define a complexification:

1. By a tensor product (this is called *extension of scalars*): $V^\mathbb{C} = V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ where $i \cdot (v \otimes w) = v \otimes iw$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. The linear map $g: V \to W$ complexifies to $g^\mathbb{C} = g \otimes 1_\mathbb{C}$.
2. We could do the same as above, but conjugate things. So define $V^\mathbb{C} = V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space, and define $i(v \otimes w) = - v \otimes iw$. We still set $g^\mathbb{C} = g \otimes 1_\mathbb{C}$.
3. By a direct sum: $V^\mathbb{C} = V \oplus V$, where $i(v_1, v_2) = (-v_2, v_1)$. The linear map $g: V \to W$ complexifies to $g^\mathbb{C}(v_1, v_2) = (g(v_1), g(v_2))$.
4. Doing the conjugate of the thing above: $V^\mathbb{C} = V \oplus V$, where $i(v_1, v_2) = (v_2, -v_1)$. We still set $g^\mathbb{C}(v_1, v_2) = (g(v_1), g(v_2))$.

What is the relationship between these methods of complexification, as functors? The answer is that they are all *isomorphic* functors, meaning that for any two of them there exists a [natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) such that each component of the natural transformation is an isomorphism.

Consider 3 and 4, which we will differentiate by writing $V^{3 \mathbb{C}}$ and $V^{4 \mathbb{C}}$. We can define a natural transformation $\eta: (-)^{3 \mathbb{C}} \to (-)^{4 \mathbb{C}}$ by setting
$$ \eta_V: V^{3 \mathbb{C}} \to V^{4 \mathbb{C}}, \quad \eta(v_1, v_2) = (v_1, -v_2).$$
We need to check that $\eta_V$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear for each $V$:
$$ \eta_V i (v_1, v_2) = \eta_V(-v_2, v_1) = (-v_2, -v_1) = i(v_1, -v_2) = i \eta_V (v_1, v_2).$$
Hence the components $\eta_V$ are all $\mathbb{C}$-linear (they lie in the correct category), and are clearly isomorphisms. We now need to verify the other condition on being a natural transformation, which is that for each map $g: V \to W$ of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, we have $\eta_W \circ g^{3 \mathbb{C}} = g^{4 \mathbb{C}} \circ \eta_V$. Indeed,
$$\eta_W g^{3 \mathbb{C}}(v_1, v_2) = \eta_W(g(v_1), g(v_2)) = (g(v_1), -g(v_2))$$
and
$$ g^{4 \mathbb{C}} \eta_V(v_1, v_2) = g^{4 \mathbb{C}}(v_1, -v_2) = (g(v_1), -g(v_2)).$$

So indeed $\eta$ gives a natural isomorphism between the third and fourth methods of complexification. We can give a natural isomorphism from the first to the fourth method, where the natural transformation $\mu: (-)^{1 \mathbb{C}} \to (-)^{3 \mathbb{C}}$ will have components
$$ \mu_V: V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \to V \oplus V, \quad \mu_V(v_1 \otimes 1 + v_2 \otimes i) = (v_1, v_2),$$
where we have used the fact that every tensor in $V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ uniquely decomposes into the form $v_1 \otimes 1 + v_2 \otimes i$. I think this should address most of your questions about the relationships between these.

---

There is something else going on here: the first and second methods are "conjugates" of each other, and the third and fourth methods are "conjugates" of each other. We can formalise this as follows.

There is a (yet another) functor $\mathbb{C}$-vect to $\mathbb{C}$-vect, the [complex conjugate space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_vector_space) functor. For a complex vector space $V$, its *conjugate vector space* is $\overline{V}$, where $\overline{V} = V$ as sets, but with the new scalar multiplication $z \cdot v = \overline{z} v$ for $v \in \overline{V}$. Given a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $g: V \to W$, the conjugate map $\overline{g}: \overline{V} \to \overline{W}$ is defined to be the same map of sets as $g$. (A pleasant exercise: even though $\overline{g}$ is the same map of sets as $g$, if you choose bases and write out a matrix for $g$, the corresponding matrix for $\overline{g}$ will have every entry conjugated).

The complexification methods 1 and 2 differ by composition with the conjugate functor, as do 3 and 4.

Last note: if we instead wrote every complex vector space as a pair $(V, J)$ of a real vector space $V$ and a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $J: V \to V$ satisfying $J^2 = -1$, then the complex conjugation functor is simply $\overline{(V, J)} = (V, -J)$. From this viewpoint, a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map is just an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map commuting with $J$, and such a map also commutes with $-J$.

Comment: Thanks, Joppy. 1. To answer Question 1, one should prove isomorphism between second and fourth methods right? 2. Do you have answer for Question 2 please? 3.  Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520787) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520648), why do we still have the same complexifications of maps in Methods 2 and 4 as, respectively, Methods 1 and 3? I'm thinking we don't really need to so we could even have additional Methods 2A and 4A where the complexifications of maps are now different from, respectively, Methods 1 and 3.

Comment: Note: I slightly edited post.

Comment: 4. Joppy, actually also,  $V^2 = (V^{\mathbb C, sum})_{\mathbb R}$ and then $V \bigotimes \mathbb R^2 = (V^{\mathbb C, tensor})_{\mathbb R}$ ? I understand in the latter case that the '$\bigotimes$' in $V \bigotimes \mathbb R^2$ has a different definition from the '$\bigotimes$' in $V \bigotimes \mathbb R^2$. However, I think $V \bigotimes \mathbb R^2 = (V^{\mathbb C, tensor})_{\mathbb R}$ because $V \bigotimes \mathbb R^2 \cong V \bigotimes (\mathbb R \bigoplus \mathbb R)$ $ \cong (V \bigotimes \mathbb R) \bigoplus (V \bigotimes \mathbb R)$ $ \cong (V) \bigoplus (V) = V^2$

Comment: Joppy, never mind my follow-up question 3 ('Based on this and this...'). I started to [analyse your answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3520956) and so I get why $(f^{\mathbb C, J})_{\mathbb R} = (f^{\mathbb C, -J})_{\mathbb R}$