# Complexification of a map under nonstandard complexifications of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here are some:

---

**Definitions, Assumptions, Notations**

Let $V$ be $\mathbb R$-vector space, possibly infinite-dimensional.

**Complexification of space definition**: Its complexification can be defined as $V^{\mathbb C} := (V^2,J)$ where $J$ is the almost complex structure $J: V^2 \to V^2, J(v,w):=(-w,v)$ which corresponds to the complex structure $s_{(J,V^2)}: \mathbb C \times V^2 \to V^2,$$ s_{(J,V^2)}(a+bi,(v,w))$$:=s_{V^2}(a,(v,w))+s_{V^2}(b,J(v,w))$$=a(v,w)+bJ(v,w)$ where $s_{V^2}$ is the real scalar multiplication on $V^2$ extended to $s_{(J,V^2)}$. In particular, $i(v,w)=(-w,v)$.

**Note on Complexification of space definition**: The above definition however depends on $J$, so to denote this dependence, we may write $V^{(\mathbb C,J)}=V^{\mathbb C}$. We could have another definition replacing $J$ with any other almost complex structure $K$ which necessarily relates to $J$ by $K = S \circ J \circ S^{-1}$ for some $S \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$. For example with $K = - J$ (I think $S$ would be $S(v,w):=(v,-w)$, which is $\mathbb C$-antilinear with respect to $J$, and even to $K=-J$ I think), we get $i(v,w)=(w,-v)$.

**Complexification of map definition**: Based on [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834) ([12.10-11 of Part I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm7KP.png)) and [Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285) ([Chapter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njg9H.png)), it looks like we can define the complexification (with respect to $J$) $f^{\mathbb C}: V^{\mathbb C} \to V^{\mathbb C}$ of $f: V \to V$, $f \in End_{\mathbb R}V$ as any of the following equivalent, I think, ways (Note: we could actually have different vector spaces such that $f: V \to U$, but I'll just talk about the case where $V=U$)

Definition 1. $f^{\mathbb C}(v,w):=(f(v),f(w))$

- I think '$\mathbb C$-linear (with respect to $J$)' isn't part of this definition but is deduced anyway.

Definition 2. $f^{\mathbb C}$ the unique $\mathbb C$-linear (with respect to $J$) map such that $f^{\mathbb C} \circ cpx = cpx \circ f$, where $cpx: V \to V^{\mathbb C}$ is the complexification map, as [Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285) ([Chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTFI.png)) calls it, or the standard embedding, as [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) calls it. (Note: I think $cpx$ doesn't depend on $J$.)

Definition 3. $f^{\mathbb C}$ the unique $\mathbb C$-linear (with respect to $J$) map such that $(f^{\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R} = f \oplus f$

Definition 4. $f^{\mathbb C} := (f \oplus f)^J$ and again '$\mathbb C$-linear (with respect to $J$)' isn't part of this definition but is deduced anyway. Here, the notation $(\cdot)^I$ is:

- **Complex structure on map definition**: The operator '$(\cdot)^I$' is supposed to be something like an inverse of the realification functor $(\cdot)_{\mathbb R}$ (see [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf) and [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834)). If $(\cdot)^I$ is some kind of functor, then $W^I := (W,I)$.

  - I couldn't find any book that uses this kind of notation, but the point of this '$g^I$' is mainly to be specific and allow shortcuts. Example: The statement '$g$ is $\mathbb C$-linear with respect to $I$' becomes just '$g^I$ is $\mathbb C$-linear'. Another example: For any almost complex structure $K$ on $W$, $K^K$ is $\mathbb C$-linear, but $I^K$ and $K^I$ are not necessarily $\mathbb C$-linear. However, with $-I$ as another almost complex structure on $W$, I think $I^{-I}$and ${-I}^{I}$ are $\mathbb C$-linear.
  - Proposition: $g^I$ is $\mathbb C$-linear if and only if $g$ is $\mathbb R$-linear and $g$ 'commutes with scalar multiplication by i (with respect to $I$)', meaning $g \circ I = I \circ g$.
  - We can also extend to defining maps like $g^{(I,H)}: (W,I) \to (U,H)$ and saying $g^{(I,H)}$ is $\mathbb C$-linear if and only if $g$ is $\mathbb R$-linear and $g \circ I = H \circ g$. In this notation and for the case of $W=U$, $g^{(I,I)}=g^I$.

Regardless of the definition, we end up with the formula given in Definition 1 (Even if the definitions aren't equivalent, whichever definitions are correct, I think will give this formula in Definition 1).

**Note on Complexification of map definition**: The above definition/s however depends on $J$, so to denote this dependence, we may write $f^{(\mathbb C,J)}=f^{\mathbb C}$.

---

**Questions**:

**Question 1**: What is the formula for $f^{(\mathbb C,K)}$ for any almost complex structure $K$ on $V^2$, assuming it exists, whether uniquely or not?

- **Note**: I actually didn't think $f^{(\mathbb C,K)}$ wouldn't be unique or even exist until mid way through typing this (so I added 2 more questions below), so there might be kind of a definition issue here, but I guess it's ok to define $f^{(\mathbb C,K)}$ as any $\mathbb C$-linear (with respect to $K$) map such that $f^{(\mathbb C,K)} \circ cpx = cpx \circ f$
- Example: For $K=-J$, I think we get still $f^{(\mathbb C,-J)}(v,w)=(f(v),f(w))$ (I derived this in a similar way that [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) derived the formula for $K=J$).
- Example: Suppose $V$ in turn has an almost complex structure $k$. Then $k \oplus k$ is an almost complex structure on $V^2$. For $K=k \oplus k$, I don't know how to get the formula for $f^{(\mathbb C,k \oplus k)}(v,w)$, similar to the cases of $K= \pm J$. Maybe it doesn't exist.

**Question 2**: Does $f^{(\mathbb C,K)}$ always exist even if not uniquely?

**Question 3**: Whenever $f^{(\mathbb C,K)}$ exists, is $f^{(\mathbb C,K)}$ unique?

---

Note: This question might be answered by the [answer, that I'm still analysing, to another question I posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu).

---

**More thoughts** based on these:

- [Bijection for involutive maps and $\mathbb R$-subspaces given almost complex structure (anti-involutive)? Formula for conjugation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/formula-for-conjugation-given-an-almost-complex-structure-and-an-mathbb-r-sub)
- [$f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes with almost complex structure and standard conjugation. What if we had anti-commutation instead?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu) ,

**It appears that**:

1. complexification relies not only on an almost complex structure $K$ on $V^2$ but also on a choice of subspace $A$ of $V^2$, where $A$ is not $V^2$ or $0$. This $A$ is what we use to identify $V$ as an embedded $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$
2. For any subspace $A$ of $V^2$, except $V^2$ and $0$, and for any almost complex structure $K$ on $V^2$, there exists a unique involutive $\mathbb R$-linear map $\sigma_{A,K}$, on $V^2$, such that $\sigma_{A,K}$ anti-commutes with $K$ and the set of fixed points of $\sigma_{A,K}$ is equal to $A$.

   - 2.1. For example, $\sigma_{V \times 0,J} = \chi$, where $\chi(v,w):=(v,-w)$
3. Therefore, I should ask about $f^{(\mathbb C,K,A)}$, not $f^{(\mathbb C,K)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Joppy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/431940)'s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3520956), this is an answer to both of the following questions

- [Complexification of a map under nonstandard complexifications of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces)
- [$f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes with almost complex structure and standard conjugation. What if we had anti-commutation instead?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu)

Here, I will derive a formula for general complexification and present generalised versions of both [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6 and [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 (but for simplicity I focus only on endomorphisms of a space rather than homomorphisms between two spaces).

---

Part 0. Assumptions:

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $A$ be an $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$ such that $A \cong V$. Let $cpx: V \to V^2$ be any injective $\mathbb R$-linear map with $image(cpx)=A$. (I guess for any $\mathbb R$-isomorphism $\gamma: V \to A$, we can choose $cpx = \iota \circ \gamma$, where $\iota: A \to V^2$ is inclusion.) Let $K \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ be any almost complex structure on $V^2$ (i.e. $K$ is anti-involutory, i.e. $K \circ K = -id_{V^2}$, i.e. $K^{-1} = -K$). Let $f \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$. Let $g \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$.

- 0.1. Intuition on $A$: $A$ is the subspace of $V^2$ that we use to identify $V$ with. Originally, this is $A=V \times 0$ and then $cpx$ is something like $cpx(v):=(v,0)$. However, I think $cpx(v):=(7v,0)$ will also work.

Part I. On $\sigma_{A,K}$ and on $K(A)$ the image of $A$ under $K$:

1. $K \circ cpx: V \to V^2$ is an injective $\mathbb R$-linear map with $image(K \circ cpx) = K(A)$.
2. $A \cong K(A)$
3. $K(A)$ is an $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$ such that $K(A) \cong V$.
4. [There exists a unique map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/bijection-for-involutive-maps-and-mathbb-r-subspaces-given-almost-complex-str) $\sigma_{A,K} \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that

   - 4.1. $\sigma_{A,K}$ is involutory, i.e. $\sigma_{A,K} \circ \sigma_{A,K} = id_{V^2}$, i.e. $\sigma_{A,K}^{-1} = \sigma_{A,K}$,
   - 4.2. $\sigma_{A,K}$ anti-commutes with $K$, i.e. $\sigma_{A,K} \circ K = - K \circ \sigma_{A,K}$, and
   - 4.3. The set of fixed points of $\sigma_{A,K}$ is equal to $A$.
5. By (I.4.1), $\sigma_{A,K}$ has exactly 2 eigenvalues $\pm 1$.
6. $A$ is also the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$.
7. $K(A)$ is both the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $-1$ of $\sigma_{A,K}$, [and the set of fixed points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558235/if-a-is-the-fixed-points-of-an-involution-sigma-then-is-ka-the-fixed-p) of $-\sigma_{A,K}$.
8. $A + K(A) = V^2$ and $A \cap K(A) = \{0_{V^2}\}$, i.e. we have a literal internal direct sum $A \bigoplus K(A) = V^2$.

Part II. On real and imaginary parts when we have commutation with $\sigma_{A,K}$:

1. If $g$ commutes or anti-commutes with $K$, we have that $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$.
2. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.
3. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.
4. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ cpx = cpx \circ G$, for some $G \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - II.4.1. $G$ turns out to be uniquely $G = cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$.
5. $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ K \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ H$, for some $H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - II.5.1. $H$ turns out to be uniquely $H = cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx$.
6. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if for some $G, H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, we can write $$g(a \oplus K(b)) = cpx \circ G \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus K \circ cpx \circ H \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$.

   - II.6.1. $g$ commutes with $K$ if and only if $G=H$.
   - II.6.2. $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ if and only if $G=-H$.
   - II.6.3. $G$ and $H$ turns out to be uniquely as given in (II.4.1) and (II.5.1).
   - II.6.4. I don't believe there's any relation between $G$ and $H$ if we don't know any further information on $g$ (e.g. commutes or anti-commutes with $K$).

Part III. For generalising [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6:

1. Just as with [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6, there exists a unique map $f_1 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_1$ commutes with $K$ and $f_1 \circ cpx = cpx \circ f$.
2. Observe that there also exists a unique map $f_2 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_2$ commutes with $K$ and $f_2 \circ K \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ f$.
3. By (II.6.1), $f_1=f_2$. Define $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}:=f_1=f_2$. Equivalently, $f^\mathbb C:=f_1^K=f_2^K$.

   - III.3.1. Meaning: The original definition of complexification is based on $cpx$. If we have another definition of complexification $K \circ cpx$ instead of $cpx$, then this definition will be equivalent to the original.
4. The formula for $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ actually turns out to be $$(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}(a \oplus K(b)) = cpx \circ f \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus K \circ cpx \circ f \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$. We can derive this similarly to the derivation in the first part of the proof of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6.
5. (I'm not sure if I use this fact anywhere in this post.) [The map that yields a complexification unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524276/questions-on-the-complexification-of-a-map): $f=h$ if and only if $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R} = (h^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$.

Part IV. For generalising [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16:

1. We can see that this formula for $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ also allows a generalisation of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16: $g=(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ for some (unique) $f$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ and $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - IV.1.1. By the way, I think [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 is better stated as 'commutes with both $J$ and $\chi$ iff complexification' instead of 'If commutes with $J$, then we have commutes with $\chi$ iff complexification' since, in the latter case, the 'if' direction doesn't use the 'commutes with $J$' assumption. It might be wrong to talk about complexification if we don't assume 'commutes with $J$', so in this case, we could say like '$g=f \oplus f$' instead of '$g$ is the complexification of some (unique) $f$')
   - IV.1.2. Equivalently, $g=(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$
   - IV.1.3. Equivalently, $g=(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$

Part V. For the analogue of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6 for anti-complexification (anti-commuting with $K$ but still commuting with $\sigma_{A,K}$):

1. Just as with [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6, there exists a unique map $f_1 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_1$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $f_1 \circ cpx = cpx \circ f$.
2. There exists a unique map $f_2 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_2$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $f_2 \circ K \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ f$.
3. However, by (II.6.2), $f_1=-f_2$.

   - V.3.1. Meaning: Hence, $f_1 \ne -f_2$, unlike with the case of complexification, where we had $f_1=f_2$. Therefore, we have two unequivalent definitions of anti-complexification.
   - V.3.2. However, observe that if we define $f^{anti-\mathbb C}:=f_1$, then $(-f)^{anti-\mathbb C}=f_2$. This way, even though $f_2$ isn't the anti-complexification of $f$, $f_2$ is still the anti-complexification of something, namely of $-f$.
   - V.3.3. Same as V.3.2, but interchange $f_1$ and $f_2$.
4. The formula for $(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ actually turns out to be (I use the $f_1$ definition) $$f_1(a \oplus K(b)) = cpx \circ f \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus K \circ cpx \circ -f \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$. We can derive this similarly to the derivation in the first part of the proof of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6.
5. (I'm not sure if I use this fact anywhere in this post.) The map that yields an anti-complexification is unique (as with complexification): $f=h$ if and only if $(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R} = (h^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$.

Part VI. For the analogue of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 for anti-complexification (anti-commuting with $K$ but still commuting with $\sigma_{A,K}$):

1. The analogue of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 for generalised anti-complexification is that: $g=f^{anti-\mathbb C}$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - VI.1.1. Equivalently, $g=(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$.

     - VI.1.1.1. However, $cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$ may be either of $\pm f$, depending on the choice of definition.
   - VI.1.2. Equivalently, $g=(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$.

     - VI.1.2.1. However, $cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx$ may be either of $\pm f$, depending on the choice of definition.
   - VI.1.3. Regardless of the definition, $cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx = - cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$.

Part VII. On real and imaginary parts when we have anti-commutation with $\sigma_{A,K}$:

1. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ G$, for some $G \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - VII.1.1. $G$ turns out to be uniquely $G = cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$.
2. $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ K \circ cpx = cpx \circ H$, for some $H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - VII.2.1. $H$ turns out to be uniquely $H = cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx$.
3. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if for some $G, H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, we can write $$g(a \oplus K(b)) = K \circ cpx \circ G \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus cpx \circ H \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$.

   - VII.3.1. Observe that both $\pm K \circ g$ commute with $K$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ (if and only if both $g \circ \pm K$ commute with $K$).
   - VII.3.2. Same as (VII.3.1), but 'anti-commute/s' instead of 'commute/s'.
   - VII.3.3. $G$ and $H$ turns out to be uniquely as given in (VII.1.1) and (VII.2.1).
   - VII.3.4. I don't believe there's any relation between $G$ and $H$ if we don't know any further information on $g$.
   - VII.3.5. By (VII.3.1), apply (II.6.1) to $K^{-1} \circ g$: $K^{-1} \circ g = (G^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $G=H$ if and only if $K^{-1} \circ g$  commutes with $K$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$.
   - VII.3.6.  By (VII.3.2), apply (II.6.2) to $K^{-1} \circ g$: $K^{-1} \circ g = (G^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ or $((-G)^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ (depending on definition) if and only if $G=-H$ if and only if $K^{-1} \circ g$  anti-commutes with $K$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$.

Part VIII. Additional remarks:

1. $g$ anti-commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$ if and only if $g=K \circ h$, for some $h \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$ that commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - VIII.1.1. This $h$ is uniquely $h = K^{-1} \circ g$
2. $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$ if and only if $g=K^{-1} \circ j$, for some $j \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$ that anti-commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - VIII.2.1. This $j$ is uniquely $j = K \circ g$