# $\mathbb R$-forms of $V^2$ i.e. subspaces that are isomorphic to $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $A$ be an $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$ that is $\mathbb R$-isomorphic to $V$. Then $A$ could be $V \times 0$ or $0 \times V$. Is every other $A$ given by $\{(v,b_Av)|v \in V\}$ for some unique $b_A \in \mathbb R \setminus 0$?

Context:

[$f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes with almost complex structure and standard conjugation. What if we had anti-commutation instead?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu)

[Complexification of a map under nonstandard complexifications of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course not. See for instance $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $$A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in V\times V\,:\, x_2=0\land x_3=0\}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I reached my vote limit, so I can't upvote right now.