# $f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes with almost complex structure and standard conjugation. What if we had anti-commutation instead?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here are some:

Let $V$ be $\mathbb R$-vector space, possibly infinite-dimensional.

**Complexification of space definition**: Its complexification can be defined as $V^{\mathbb C} := (V^2,J)$ where $J$ is the almost complex structure $J: V^2 \to V^2, J(v,w):=(-w,v)$ which corresponds to the complex structure $s_{(J,V^2)}: \mathbb C \times V^2 \to V^2,$$ s_{(J,V^2)}(a+bi,(v,w))$$:=s_{V^2}(a,(v,w))+s_{V^2}(b,J(v,w))$$=a(v,w)+bJ(v,w)$ where $s_{V^2}$ is the real scalar multiplication on $V^2$ extended to $s_{(J,V^2)}$. In particular, $i(v,w)=(-w,v)$.

**Complexification of map definition**: See [a question I posted previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces).

**Proposition** ([Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf)): Let $f \in End_{\mathbb C}(V^{\mathbb C})$. We have that $f$ is the complexification of a map if and only if $f$ commutes with the standard conjugation map $\chi$ on $V^{\mathbb C}$, $\chi(v,w):=(v,-w)$. In symbols:

If $f \circ J = J \circ f$, then the following are equivalent:

- Condition 1. $f=g^{\mathbb C}$ for some $g \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$
- Condition 2. $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$

  - I think [Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf) would rewrite Condition 2 as $f = \chi \circ f \circ \chi$ and say $f$ 'equals its own conjugate'.

**Questions:** Considering the half of the above proposition that says '$f$ commutes with both $J$ and $\chi$ implies $f$ is complexification of a map', what do we get if we instead have the following?

1. commutes with $J$ and anti-commutes with $\chi$ ($f \circ \chi = - \chi \circ f$)
2. anti-commutes with $J$ ($f \circ J = - J \circ f$, i.e. $f$ is $\mathbb C$-anti-linear) and commutes with $\chi$
3. anti-commutes with $J$ and anti-commutes with $\chi$

**Motivation**: $f=J$ satisfies the case in Question 1, and $f=\chi$ satisfies the case in Question 2.

**Guess** (for Question 2):

Similar to [this (the $K=-J$ part)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces), I kind of had the idea to define something like anti-complexification of a map: for $g \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, $g^{anti-\mathbb C}$ is any $\mathbb C$-anti-linear map such that $g^{anti-\mathbb C} \circ cpx = cpx \circ g$, where $cpx: V \to V^{\mathbb C}$ is the complexification map, as [Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285) ([Chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTFI.png)) calls it, or the standard embedding, as [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) calls it. I think $g^{anti-\mathbb C}$ turns out to always exist uniquely as $g^{anti-\mathbb C}(v,w)=(g(v),-g(w))$.

Then, I think the answer for Question 2 is that $f$ is the anti-complexification of a map. We can strengthen the result to: Let $f$ be $\mathbb C$-anti-linear on $V^{\mathbb C}$, i.e. $f$ anti-commutes with $J$. We have that $f$ is the anti-complexification of a map $g \in End_{\mathbb R}V$, i.e. $f=g^{anti-\mathbb C}$  if and only if $f$ commutes with the standard conjugation map $\chi$, i.e. $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$.

In the case of $f=\chi$ for Question 2,  $f=\chi = g^{anti-\mathbb C}$ for $g=id_{V}$, the identity map on $V$, which by the way gives us $(id_{V})^{\mathbb C} = id_{V^{\mathbb C}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to get things straight in my head every time I do this. Let $V^2$ be a complex vector space. This is equivalent to the data of a real vector space $V^2$, along with an $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator $J: V^2 \to V^2$ satisfying $J^2 = -1$. We will say that an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $T: V^2 \to V^2$ is *$\mathbb{C}$-linear* if $TJ = JT$, and *$\mathbb{C}$-antilinear* if $TJ = -JT$.

You cannot "de-complexify" $(V^2, J)$, or connect it to an original un-complexified space, without a conjugation map $\chi: V^2 \to V^2$, by which we mean an $\mathbb{R}$-linear, $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear operator satisfying $\chi^2 = 1$. Once we have such a $\chi$, we can decompose $V^2$ into a real subspace $V^2_{\mathrm{re}}$ as the 1-eigenspace of $\chi$, and $V^2_{\mathrm{im}}$ as the (-1)-eigenspace of $\chi$. Note that $J$ gives a choice of isomorphism $V_{\mathrm{re}} \to V_{\mathrm{im}}$, and so does $J^{-1} = -J$.

Now consider the whole structure $(V^2, J, \chi)$. Given an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $g: V^2_{\mathrm{re}} \to V^2_{\mathrm{re}}$, we can *complexify* it by defining how it acts on "real and imaginary parts", across the direct sum decomposition $V^2 = V_\mathrm{re} \oplus V_\mathrm{im}$. Note that we need to apply $J$ to an imaginary part to make it real, apply $g$, then apply $J^{-1} = -J$ to send it back to the imaginary subspace:
$$ g^\mathbb{C}(v_{\mathrm{re}} + v_{\mathrm{im}}) = g(v_{\mathrm{re}}) - J g( J v_{\mathrm{im}}).$$
Let's quickly check that this is indeed $\mathbb{C}$-linear:
$$ \begin{aligned}
g^\mathbb{C} J (v_{\mathrm{re}} + v_{\mathrm{im}})
&= g^\mathbb{C}(J v_\mathrm{im} + J v_{\mathrm{re}}) \\
&= g(J v_\mathrm{im}) - J g(J^2 v_{\mathrm{re}}) \\
&= J (g(v_\mathrm{re}) - J g (J v_\mathrm{im})) \\
&= J g^\mathbb{C}(v_\mathrm{re} + v_\mathrm{im}).
\end{aligned}$$
It's quite simple to check the commutation property of the conjugation $\chi$ with a complexification $g^\mathbb{C}$: since $\chi$ acts by $1$ on $V^2_\mathrm{re}$, $-1$ on $V^2_\mathrm{im}$ and anticommutes with $J$, we have
$$ \chi g^\mathbb{C}(v_{\mathrm{re}} + v_{\mathrm{im}}) = g(v_{\mathrm{re}}) + J g(J v_\mathrm{im}) = g^\mathbb{C}(v_{\mathrm{re}} - v_{\mathrm{im}}) = g^\mathbb{C} \chi (v_{\mathrm{re}} + v_{\mathrm{im}}).$$
You can also see that if we wanted to define the *anticomplexification* of $g$, we could just swap out the $+$ sign for a $-$ sign in the formula for $g^\mathbb{C}$, which would make it anticommute with $J$.

---

Now consider our $(V^2, J, \chi)$ and consider any $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $f: V^2 \to V^2$ and its potential $\chi$-commutation properties:

1. $\chi f = f \chi$ is equivalent to $f(V^2_\mathrm{re}) \subseteq V^2_\mathrm{re}$ and $f(V^2_\mathrm{im}) \subseteq V^2_\mathrm{im}$.
2. $\chi f = - f \chi$ is equivalent to $f(V^2_\mathrm{re}) \subseteq V^2_\mathrm{im}$ and $f(V^2_\mathrm{im}) \subseteq V^2_\mathrm{re}$.
3. Note that replacing $f$ by $Jf$ swaps 1. and 2.

So the four classes of maps you are considering are complexifications, anticomplexifications, and $J$ multiplied by the first two.

Note that commutation with $\chi$ is really about doing something to the real and imaginary subspaces: either preserving them or swapping them. However, the action on $f$ on each of these subspaces could be wildly different, for example the action on $V^2_\mathrm{re}$ could be the identity, while on $V^2_\mathrm{im}$ it might be zero. Commutation with $J$ will ensure the actions are similar, in the sense that we can conjugate one action into another via the identity $f = - J f J$. This is the kind of intuition I have: $\chi$ is a choice of real and imaginary subspaces, and $J$ is the "rotation" which identifies them.

Comment: Incredible. Thanks Joppy. I think the intuition of $f(real) \subseteq real$ is insanely brilliant. Also, I think your answer kind of answers some of my other questions (both the ones I already posted and the ones I haven't yet). Can you answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520817/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-structure-j-and-conj) one also please?

Comment: Also Joppy, do you have any references for your answer please?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I'm sorry but I can't really quote many references for this answer. This answer is a result of me struggling with understanding complex structures on real vector spaces and real structures on complex spaces some time ago.

What I do think is important to pay attention to is the role of $\chi$ defining $V_\mathrm{re}$ and $V_\mathrm{im}$, and noting that to complexify a map you still need to use $J$ to go between those two spaces. This is hidden when you start with a complexified space, rather than just a complex vector space.

Comment: Joppy, may you please answer any of my bounty questions? [Complexification of a map under nonstandard complexifications of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces), [Eigenvalues and eigenspaces of almost complex structures under each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524239/eigenvalues-and-eigenspaces-of-almost-complex-structures-under-each-other)

Comment: Joppy, I started analysing your answer. In the following sentence, I use the terms 'external' and 'internal' in [this sense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518339/is-there-a-notion-that-0-mathbb-ri-or-mathbb-r-0i-has-an-internal-com). Do you mean that our standard definition of what seems to be an external complexification of $g: V \to V$ is your given definition of what seems to be an internal complexification of $g \times 0: V\times 0 \to V \times 0$ with $(V^2)_{re} = V \times 0$? (Note: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3537806) may be relevant)

Comment: I don't think "internal" vs "external" complexification matters. I prefer to just think of a real vector space $V$ and a complex structure $J: V \to V$. If it happens to be that $V$ has been constructed from some other half-dimensional vector space $W$ by setting $V = W \oplus W$, and $J(w_1, w_2) = (-w_2, w_1)$ then that's fine, but it can be analysed in exactly the same way as just $(V, J)$.

Trying to relate different complexifications by comparing underlying sets is misguided. As I pointed out in my other answer, what you really should care about is the complexification _functor_.

Comment: Joppy, I mean like: Conrad, Roman and Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin complexify $f: V \to V$ to get $f^{\mathbb C}: V^{\mathbb C}  \to V^{\mathbb C}$. When they are doing this, are they doing the same thing you do with $(V^2)_{re} = V \times 0$  (and $J$ as the canonical $J(v,w):=(-w,v)$) to complexify $f \times 0: V \times 0 \to V \times 0$, i.e. your $(f \times 0)^{\mathbb C}$ is equal to their $f^{\mathbb C}$?

Comment: Joppy, I posted an answer. May you please verify?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Joppy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/431940)'s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3520956), this is an answer to both of the following questions

- [Complexification of a map under nonstandard complexifications of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces)
- [$f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes with almost complex structure and standard conjugation. What if we had anti-commutation instead?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu)

Here, I will derive a formula for general complexification and present generalised versions of both [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6 and [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 (but for simplicity I focus only on endomorphisms of a space rather than homomorphisms between two spaces).

---

Part 0. Assumptions:

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $A$ be an $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$ such that $A \cong V$. Let $cpx: V \to V^2$ be any injective $\mathbb R$-linear map with $image(cpx)=A$. (I guess for any $\mathbb R$-isomorphism $\gamma: V \to A$, we can choose $cpx = \iota \circ \gamma$, where $\iota: A \to V^2$ is inclusion.) Let $K \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ be any almost complex structure on $V^2$ (i.e. $K$ is anti-involutory, i.e. $K \circ K = -id_{V^2}$, i.e. $K^{-1} = -K$). Let $f \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$. Let $g \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$.

- 0.1. Intuition on $A$: $A$ is the subspace of $V^2$ that we use to identify $V$ with. Originally, this is $A=V \times 0$ and then $cpx$ is something like $cpx(v):=(v,0)$. However, I think $cpx(v):=(7v,0)$ will also work.

Part I. On $\sigma_{A,K}$ and on $K(A)$ the image of $A$ under $K$:

1. $K \circ cpx: V \to V^2$ is an injective $\mathbb R$-linear map with $image(K \circ cpx) = K(A)$.
2. $A \cong K(A)$
3. $K(A)$ is an $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$ such that $K(A) \cong V$.
4. [There exists a unique map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/bijection-for-involutive-maps-and-mathbb-r-subspaces-given-almost-complex-str) $\sigma_{A,K} \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that

   - 4.1. $\sigma_{A,K}$ is involutory, i.e. $\sigma_{A,K} \circ \sigma_{A,K} = id_{V^2}$, i.e. $\sigma_{A,K}^{-1} = \sigma_{A,K}$,
   - 4.2. $\sigma_{A,K}$ anti-commutes with $K$, i.e. $\sigma_{A,K} \circ K = - K \circ \sigma_{A,K}$, and
   - 4.3. The set of fixed points of $\sigma_{A,K}$ is equal to $A$.
5. By (I.4.1), $\sigma_{A,K}$ has exactly 2 eigenvalues $\pm 1$.
6. $A$ is also the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$.
7. $K(A)$ is both the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $-1$ of $\sigma_{A,K}$, [and the set of fixed points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558235/if-a-is-the-fixed-points-of-an-involution-sigma-then-is-ka-the-fixed-p) of $-\sigma_{A,K}$.
8. $A + K(A) = V^2$ and $A \cap K(A) = \{0_{V^2}\}$, i.e. we have a literal internal direct sum $A \bigoplus K(A) = V^2$.

Part II. On real and imaginary parts when we have commutation with $\sigma_{A,K}$:

1. If $g$ commutes or anti-commutes with $K$, we have that $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$.
2. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.
3. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.
4. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ cpx = cpx \circ G$, for some $G \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - II.4.1. $G$ turns out to be uniquely $G = cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$.
5. $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ K \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ H$, for some $H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - II.5.1. $H$ turns out to be uniquely $H = cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx$.
6. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if for some $G, H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, we can write $$g(a \oplus K(b)) = cpx \circ G \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus K \circ cpx \circ H \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$.

   - II.6.1. $g$ commutes with $K$ if and only if $G=H$.
   - II.6.2. $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ if and only if $G=-H$.
   - II.6.3. $G$ and $H$ turns out to be uniquely as given in (II.4.1) and (II.5.1).
   - II.6.4. I don't believe there's any relation between $G$ and $H$ if we don't know any further information on $g$ (e.g. commutes or anti-commutes with $K$).

Part III. For generalising [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6:

1. Just as with [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6, there exists a unique map $f_1 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_1$ commutes with $K$ and $f_1 \circ cpx = cpx \circ f$.
2. Observe that there also exists a unique map $f_2 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_2$ commutes with $K$ and $f_2 \circ K \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ f$.
3. By (II.6.1), $f_1=f_2$. Define $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}:=f_1=f_2$. Equivalently, $f^\mathbb C:=f_1^K=f_2^K$.

   - III.3.1. Meaning: The original definition of complexification is based on $cpx$. If we have another definition of complexification $K \circ cpx$ instead of $cpx$, then this definition will be equivalent to the original.
4. The formula for $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ actually turns out to be $$(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}(a \oplus K(b)) = cpx \circ f \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus K \circ cpx \circ f \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$. We can derive this similarly to the derivation in the first part of the proof of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6.
5. (I'm not sure if I use this fact anywhere in this post.) [The map that yields a complexification unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524276/questions-on-the-complexification-of-a-map): $f=h$ if and only if $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R} = (h^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$.

Part IV. For generalising [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16:

1. We can see that this formula for $(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ also allows a generalisation of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16: $g=(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ for some (unique) $f$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ and $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - IV.1.1. By the way, I think [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 is better stated as 'commutes with both $J$ and $\chi$ iff complexification' instead of 'If commutes with $J$, then we have commutes with $\chi$ iff complexification' since, in the latter case, the 'if' direction doesn't use the 'commutes with $J$' assumption. It might be wrong to talk about complexification if we don't assume 'commutes with $J$', so in this case, we could say like '$g=f \oplus f$' instead of '$g$ is the complexification of some (unique) $f$')
   - IV.1.2. Equivalently, $g=(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$
   - IV.1.3. Equivalently, $g=(f^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$

Part V. For the analogue of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6 for anti-complexification (anti-commuting with $K$ but still commuting with $\sigma_{A,K}$):

1. Just as with [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6, there exists a unique map $f_1 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_1$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $f_1 \circ cpx = cpx \circ f$.
2. There exists a unique map $f_2 \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $f_2$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $f_2 \circ K \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ f$.
3. However, by (II.6.2), $f_1=-f_2$.

   - V.3.1. Meaning: Hence, $f_1 \ne -f_2$, unlike with the case of complexification, where we had $f_1=f_2$. Therefore, we have two unequivalent definitions of anti-complexification.
   - V.3.2. However, observe that if we define $f^{anti-\mathbb C}:=f_1$, then $(-f)^{anti-\mathbb C}=f_2$. This way, even though $f_2$ isn't the anti-complexification of $f$, $f_2$ is still the anti-complexification of something, namely of $-f$.
   - V.3.3. Same as V.3.2, but interchange $f_1$ and $f_2$.
4. The formula for $(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ actually turns out to be (I use the $f_1$ definition) $$f_1(a \oplus K(b)) = cpx \circ f \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus K \circ cpx \circ -f \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$. We can derive this similarly to the derivation in the first part of the proof of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 2.6.
5. (I'm not sure if I use this fact anywhere in this post.) The map that yields an anti-complexification is unique (as with complexification): $f=h$ if and only if $(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R} = (h^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$.

Part VI. For the analogue of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 for anti-complexification (anti-commuting with $K$ but still commuting with $\sigma_{A,K}$):

1. The analogue of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) Theorem 4.16 for generalised anti-complexification is that: $g=f^{anti-\mathbb C}$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - VI.1.1. Equivalently, $g=(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$.

     - VI.1.1.1. However, $cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$ may be either of $\pm f$, depending on the choice of definition.
   - VI.1.2. Equivalently, $g=(f^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$.

     - VI.1.2.1. However, $cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx$ may be either of $\pm f$, depending on the choice of definition.
   - VI.1.3. Regardless of the definition, $cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx = - cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$.

Part VII. On real and imaginary parts when we have anti-commutation with $\sigma_{A,K}$:

1. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ cpx = K \circ cpx \circ G$, for some $G \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - VII.1.1. $G$ turns out to be uniquely $G = cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} \circ g \circ cpx$.
2. $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if $g \circ K \circ cpx = cpx \circ H$, for some $H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$.

   - VII.2.1. $H$ turns out to be uniquely $H = cpx^{-1} \circ g \circ K \circ cpx$.
3. $image(g \circ cpx) \subseteq image(K \circ cpx)$ and $image(g \circ K \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$ if and only if for some $G, H \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, we can write $$g(a \oplus K(b)) = K \circ cpx \circ G \circ cpx^{-1}(a) \oplus cpx \circ H \circ cpx^{-1} \circ K^{-1} (K(b)),$$ where $a,b \in A = image(cpx)$.

   - VII.3.1. Observe that both $\pm K \circ g$ commute with $K$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$ (if and only if both $g \circ \pm K$ commute with $K$).
   - VII.3.2. Same as (VII.3.1), but 'anti-commute/s' instead of 'commute/s'.
   - VII.3.3. $G$ and $H$ turns out to be uniquely as given in (VII.1.1) and (VII.2.1).
   - VII.3.4. I don't believe there's any relation between $G$ and $H$ if we don't know any further information on $g$.
   - VII.3.5. By (VII.3.1), apply (II.6.1) to $K^{-1} \circ g$: $K^{-1} \circ g = (G^\mathbb C)_{\mathbb R}$ if and only if $G=H$ if and only if $K^{-1} \circ g$  commutes with $K$ if and only if $g$ commutes with $K$.
   - VII.3.6.  By (VII.3.2), apply (II.6.2) to $K^{-1} \circ g$: $K^{-1} \circ g = (G^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ or $((-G)^{anti-\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R}$ (depending on definition) if and only if $G=-H$ if and only if $K^{-1} \circ g$  anti-commutes with $K$ if and only if $g$ anti-commutes with $K$.

Part VIII. Additional remarks:

1. $g$ anti-commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$ if and only if $g=K \circ h$, for some $h \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$ that commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - VIII.1.1. This $h$ is uniquely $h = K^{-1} \circ g$
2. $g$ commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$ if and only if $g=K^{-1} \circ j$, for some $j \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$ that anti-commutes with $\sigma_{A,K}$.

   - VIII.2.1. This $j$ is uniquely $j = K \circ g$

Comment: This answer is _very_ long. Is there something wrong with the definition of complexification as a functor? There is no “one true” complexification, there are instead tons of constructions which are isomorphic (as functors from real vector spaces to complex vector spaces). Anyway, im glad you solved your problem, but it’s still unclear what that problem actually was (and why it required such a long answer)

Comment: @Joppy About your last sentence, I really didn't know the correct questions to ask here. I was hoping there would be some book out there that would tell me, but your answer was the closest I could find. Thank you for all your help so far, Joppy.