# $f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes with structure $J$ and conjugation $\chi$. What is the relationship between $J$ and $\chi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here are some:

Let $V$ be $\mathbb R$-vector space, possibly infinite-dimensional.

**Complexification of space definition**: Its complexification can be defined as $V^{\mathbb C} := (V^2,J)$ where $J$ is the almost complex structure $J: V^2 \to V^2, J(v,w):=(-w,v)$ which corresponds to the complex structure $s_{(J,V^2)}: \mathbb C \times V^2 \to V^2,$$ s_{(J,V^2)}(a+bi,(v,w))$$:=s_{V^2}(a,(v,w))+s_{V^2}(b,J(v,w))$$=a(v,w)+bJ(v,w)$ where $s_{V^2}$ is the real scalar multiplication on $V^2$ extended to $s_{(J,V^2)}$. In particular, $i(v,w)=(-w,v)$.

**Complexification of map definition**: See [a question I posted previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces).

**Proposition 1** ([Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf)): Let $f \in End_{\mathbb C}(V^{\mathbb C})$. We have that $f$ is the complexification of a map if and only if $f$ commutes with the standard conjugation map $\chi$ on $V^{\mathbb C}$, $\chi: V^2 \to V^2$, $\chi(v,w):=(v,-w)$ (Or $\chi^J: (V^2,J)=V^{\mathbb C} \to V^{\mathbb C}$, $\chi^J(v,w):=(v,-w)$, where $\chi^J$ is $\chi$ but viewed as map on $\mathbb C$-vector space $V^{\mathbb C}$ instead of a map on $\mathbb R$-vector space $V^2$. See the bullet after ['Definition 4' here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces)). In symbols:

If $f \circ J = J \circ f$, then the following are equivalent:

- Condition 1. $f=g^{\mathbb C}$ for some $g \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$
- Condition 2. $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$

  - I think [Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf) would rewrite Condition 2 as $f = \chi \circ f \circ \chi$ and say $f$ 'equals its own conjugate'.

**Proposition 2**: $\chi \circ J = - J \circ \chi$, i.e. $\chi: V^2 \to V^2$ is $\mathbb C$-anti-linear with respect to $J$, i.e. $\chi^J: (V^2,J)=V^{\mathbb C} \to V^{\mathbb C}$ is $\mathbb C$-anti-linear, i.e. $J$ anti-commutes with $\chi$, i.e. $J$ is the negative of 'its own conjugate'.

**Question 1**: What exactly is the relationship between the ([seemingly standard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518259/nonstandard-definitions-of-complexifications)) almost complex structure $J$ and the standard conjugation $\chi$ that tells us that if $f$ commutes both with $J$ and with $\chi$, then $f$ is the complexification of a map?

- Well, $f$ commutes with $J$ if and only if $f$ commutes with $-J$. Similarly, $f$ commutes with $\chi$ if and only if $f$ commutes with $-\chi$, so $f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes both-(with $J$ or, equivalently, with $-J$)-and-(with $\chi$ or, equivalently, with $-\chi$)
- Proposition 2 obviously gives a way that $\chi$ and $J$ are related, but I think Proposition 2 does not tell us much because we can replace $\chi$ not only with $-\chi$ and not only with any conjugation on $V^{\mathbb C}$ but also with any $\mathbb C$-anti-linear map on $V^{\mathbb C}$.

**Motivation**:

1. From almost complex structure to conjugation: I'm thinking that of what '$\chi$' (or $\chi$'s)  would be if we used a [nonstandard definition of complexification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces). If we had $V^{(\mathbb C, K)} = (V^2,K)$ for some almost complex structure $K$ on $V^2$ (such as anything besides $\pm J$), then we might say, for any $f \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ with $f \circ K = K \circ f$, that $f=g^{(\mathbb C,K)}$ if and only if $f \circ$ '$\chi$' = '$\chi$' $\circ f$ assuming '$g^{(\mathbb C,K)}$' is defined (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces)).

   - 1.1. (Added on February 3, 2020) Since the set of fixed points of the original $\chi$ (for the original $K=J$) is equal to the image of the complexification map $cpx: V \to V^{\mathbb C}$, $cpx(v):=(v,0_V)$ (see [Chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTFI.png) of [Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285); [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) calls this the standard embedding), I guess we will have to change our notion of 'complexification map'. Maybe $V \times 0$ will not be the 'standard' (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532408/what-exactly-is-the-relationship-between-the-concepts-of-conjugate-complex-vecto)) $\mathbb R$-subspace of $(V^2,K)$ as it was for $K=J$ (because somehow $\chi$ is the standard conjugation for $K=J$).
2. From conjugation to almost complex structure: I am really not sure what is the correct question to ask here which is why I was reading as many references as possible, but it's kind of a headache to even formulate the question here, especially considering that calling a map a 'conjugation' depends on the almost complex structure in the first place. I think [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834) (specifically [12.9b of Part I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMvcQ.png)) could be helpful.

**Question 2**: Besides Propositions 1 and 2 and whatever answer/s is/are given for Question 1, what are some relationships between the ([seemingly standard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518259/nonstandard-definitions-of-complexifications)) almost complex structure $J$ and the standard conjugation $\chi$?

---

**(Later added) More thoughts on the above:**

Based on the equivalent condition of $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$ given in an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu) (I'm still analysing this answer) and based on [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf)'s proof of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf)'s Theorem 4.16, I make the following observations:

1. For any $f \in End_{\mathbb R+0i}(V^{\mathbb C})$, whether or not $f \in End_{\mathbb C}(V^{\mathbb C})$, we have that $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$, we have that there exist unique $g,h \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$ such that $f = (g \oplus g)^J$ on $V \times 0$ and $f = (h \oplus h)^J$ on $0 \times V = J(0 \times V)$. Hence, (on all of $V^{\mathbb C}$) $f = (g \oplus h)^J$, i.e. $f_{\mathbb R} = g \oplus h$
2. From [Chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTFI.png) of [Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), we have the complexification map $cpx: V \to V^{\mathbb C}$ (see ), $cpx(v):=(v,0_V)$. [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) calls this the standard embedding.

   - 2.1. The set of fixed points of $\chi$ is equal to the image of $cpx$.
3. We can similarly define what I like to call the anti-complexification map $anticpx: V \to V^{\mathbb C}$, $anticpx(v):=(0_V,v)$.

   - 3.1. The fixed points of $-\chi$ is equal to the image of $anticpx$.
4. Because $f \in End_{\mathbb R+0i}(V^{\mathbb C})$, $f$ commutes with scalar multiplication by $-1$ and so '$f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$' is equivalent to '$f \circ (-\chi) = (-\chi) \circ f$'.
5. I like to think that:

   - 5a. Observation 2.1 and $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$ are what give us the $g$ as $g:= cpx^{-1} \circ f \circ cpx$: In this case, $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$ for $V \times 0 = image(cpx)$ gives us $image(f \circ cpx) \subseteq image(cpx)$.
   - 5b. $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$ and Observation 3.1. don't *directly* give us $h$, in the sense that it's $f \circ (-\chi) = (-\chi) \circ f$ and Observation 3.1 that (directly) give us $h:=anticpx^{-1} \circ f \circ anticpx$: In this case, $f \circ (-\chi) = (-\chi) \circ f$ for $0 \times V = image(anticpx)$ gives us $image(f \circ anticpx) \subseteq image(anticpx)$.
6. We can view [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf)'s Theorem 4.16 as saying that if $f \in End_{\mathbb R+0i}(V^{\mathbb C})$ and if $f \circ J = J \circ f$, then '$f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$' is equivalent to '$f=(g \oplus g)^J$ for some $g \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$'.

   - 6.1. (I guess we need not say $g$ is unique since I guess we have that for any $g,h \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, $g \oplus g = h \oplus h$ on all of $V^2$ if and only if $g=h$).
7. However, it seems now that we can view [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf)'s Theorem 4.16 as saying that if $f \circ \chi = \chi \circ f$, or equivalently, that $f$ decomposes into $f=(g \oplus h)^J$ as described in Observation 1, then '$f \circ J = J \circ f$' if and only if '$g=h$' proved as follows:

   - Proof: (If) Suppose $g=h$. Then $f \circ J = J \circ f$ because for any $g \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, $(g \oplus g)^J$ is $\mathbb C$-linear. (Only if) Suppose $f \circ J = J \circ f$. Then $(0_V,h(v))=f(0_V,v)=$$(f \circ J)(v,0_V)=(J \circ f)(v,0_V)=$$J(g(v),0_V)=(0_V,g(v))$ for all $v \in V$. QED
8. I just realised after typing all of Observations 1 - 7 that I think Observations 1 - 7 are more for Motivation 2 than for Motivation 1.

   - 8.1. For Motivation 1, I think we can think of, for any $K$, finding $\chi_K$ such that '$f: (V^2,K) \to (V^2,K)$ is the complexification (with respect to $K$) of a map' if and only if $f$ commutes with $\chi_K$.
   - 8.2. For Motivation 2, I think we can think of, for any $\gamma: V^2 \to V^2$ such that '$f: V^2 \to V^2$ commutes with $\gamma$' is equivalent to '$f$ decomposes into $f=g \oplus h$', finding $K_{\gamma}$ such that '$f$ commutes with $K_{\gamma}$' is equivalent to some condition $P(g,h)$ on $g$ and $h$ that is equivalent to saying that '$f^{K_{\gamma}}$ is $\mathbb C$-linear'.

     - 8.2.1. For example: with $\gamma=\chi$ and $K=J$, we have $P(g,h)=$'$g=h$'. With $\gamma=\chi$ and $K=-J$, I think we have $P(g,h)=$'$g=-h$'
     - 8.2.2. I guess '$\gamma: W \to W$ such that '$f: W \to W$ commutes with $\gamma$' is equivalent to '$f$ decomposes into $f=g \oplus h$' is the definition of a 'conjugation' on an $\mathbb R$-vector space $W$ that [isn't odd-dimensional if it were finite-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518448) or at least is equal to the external direct sum $W = U \bigoplus U$ for some $\mathbb R$-vector space $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe $\chi$ and $J$ are related by $V \times 0$.

**Part I of explanation**:

For the two choices of

1. $J(v,w):=(-w,v)$ as the almost complex structure on $V^2$ that we use to define complexification of both $V$ and $\mathbb R$-endomorphisms $f$ of $V$ and
2. $V \times 0$ as the $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$ that we use to identify $V$,

we will uniquely get $\chi(v,w):=(v,-w)$ as the unique involutive $\mathbb R$-linear map on $V^2$ such that $\chi^J$ is $\mathbb C$-anti-linear and the set of fixed points of $\chi$ is equal to $V \times 0$.

In other words:

If we were to try solve for the possible $\sigma$'s, $\sigma \in End_{\mathbb R} (V^2)$, such that

1. $\sigma \circ J = - J \circ \sigma$,
2. $\sigma \circ \sigma = id_{V^2}$
3. The set of fixed points of $\sigma$ is equal to $V \times 0$, then

we would get that the unique solution to the above system of 3 equations (2 matrix equations and 1 set equation) is $\sigma = \chi$.

**Part II of explanation**:

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Define $K \in Aut_{\mathbb R} (V^2)$ as *anti-involutive* if $K^2 = -id_{V^2}$. Observe that $K$ is anti-involutive on $V^2$ if and only if $K$ is an almost complex structure on $V^2$. Let $\Gamma(V^2)$ be the $\mathbb R$-subspaces of $V^2$ that are isomorphic to $V$ (i.e. $\mathbb R$-subspaces of $V^2$ except for $V^2$ and $0$). Let $AI(V^2)$ and $I(V^2)$ be, respectively, the anti-involutive and involutive maps on $V^2$.

[Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf)'s Theorem 4.11 without reference to complex numbers seems to be able to be restated as:

> Let $V$ be $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $J(v,w):=(-w,v)$. There exists a bijection between $\Gamma(V^2)$ and involutive $\mathbb R$-linear maps that anti-commute with $J$.

And then possibly (I ask about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/formula-for-conjugation-given-an-almost-complex-structure-and-an-mathbb-r-sub)) generalised to:

> Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $K \in AI(V^2)$. There exists a bijection between $\Gamma(V^2)$ and involutive $\mathbb R$-linear maps $\sigma$ that anti-commute with $K$.

**Part III of explanation**:

In relation to the [answer in the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu) (which I've started to analyse), it appears we have that $V \times 0$ is the '$V^2_{re}$' (I believe '$V^2_{re}$' represents an arbitrary element of $\Gamma(V^2)$) that we use to identify $V$ as an embedded $\mathbb R$-subspace of $V^2$.